# How does Sinatra's `put` work?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, put

`get` in Sinatra displays whatever you want when you type the path into the URL. I don't `put`. How do you call `put`?

I am trying to run

```
put '/:name' do |name|
  puts "hello " + name
end
```

How do I actually call this? I type into my browser:

```
http://localhost:4567/examplename\
```

but when I read it in my terminal (cmd prompt), it tries to access it as `get`. What am I missing regarding how `put` works?

Comment: You have to make a PUT request like with curl, httpie, Postman, etc.

Comment: See here: http://mikeebert.tumblr.com/post/26877173686/quick-tip-using-put-and-delete-in-sinatra, but replace the line where he says, ***In order to use POST in Sinatra...*** with ***In order to use PUT in Sinatra...***  Also, check out the links he refers to.

Comment: @NKijak OMG I GET PAID FOR THIS?! Dave n' Buster tokens?

Comment: Also see **method_override** configuration setting here: http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html

Comment: A helpful synopsis and list of HTTP verbs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `put` method corresponds with an HTTP `PUT` request. If you're making a `GET`, which is what the browser does by default, you should change that to:

```
get '/:name' do |name|
  # ...
end
```

If you're talking about "how do I write to the browser" then you need this:

```
get '/:name' do |name|
  "hello #{name}"
end
```

Don't write things to STDOUT with `puts`, just return the content you want to be sent. That's how Sinatra works.

If you want to make a `PUT` request you need to tell your tool to use that method. For example, with `curl -X PUT`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Advanced REST Client Chrome Extension. Enter your URL in the URL field, select PUT for the http verb and click on Send button. You will the result in the Response text area.